# Cannot find crontab entry for a scheduled shell script

Tags: linux, cron

My predecessor set up a basic installation of CrunchBang in a VirtualBox VM - The Windows host runs a scheduled task to boot the VM, then CrunchBang runs a shell script some 10-15 minutes later to rsync some files to a local drive. Windows is booting the VM just fine, and CrunchBang's script appears to be functioning correctly and running according to its schedule. But I would like to tweak CrunchBang's schedule a bit, and I can't figure out how/where the script is being scheduled. **crontab -l** returns **no crontab for *xxx*** for both the default user and root, and **crontab -e** likewise results in empty files.

Is there another location where the schedule entry could be saved? An alternative to cron that may be running it instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check under /etc/cron.d/ for scripts.

Comment: Also, /etc/crontab.

Comment: There are only two files there, **.placeholder** and **update-motd**, neither of which has an entry for my script.

Comment: @cjc, I found it in /etc/crontab. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If it's starting a consistent 15 minutes after boot, it might be a startup script that has a built-in delay/sleep before running.  You might also look at /etc/rc.local, or in /etc/init.d, in case it's not cron.